# How do I show only the name of results from `guix search`

Tags: guix

When I run for example `guix search openjdk` I get a long list of information, most of which I'm not interested in:

```
name: openjdk
version: 9.181
outputs: out jdk doc
systems: x86_64-linux i686-linux
dependencies: alsa-lib@1.2.3.2 cups@2.3.3 fontconfig@2.13.1 freetype@2.10.1 giflib@5.2.1 icedtea@3.7.0 lcms@2.9
+ libelf@0.8.13 libice@1.0.10 libjpeg-turbo@2.0.4 libpng@1.6.37 libx11@1.6.9 libxcomposite@0.4.5 libxi@1.7.10
+ libxinerama@1.1.4 libxrender@0.9.10 libxt@1.2.0 libxtst@1.2.3 make@4.2.1 unzip@6.0 which@2.21 zip@3.0
location: gnu/packages/java.scm:1872:2
homepage: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/
license: GPL 2+
synopsis: Java development kit  
description: This package provides the Java development kit OpenJDK.
relevance: 22

name: openjdk
version: 14.0
outputs: out jdk doc
systems: x86_64-linux i686-linux
dependencies: alsa-lib@1.2.3.2 autoconf@2.69 cups@2.3.3 fontconfig@2.13.1 freetype@2.10.1 giflib@5.2.1 lcms@2.9
+ libjpeg-turbo@2.0.4 libpng@1.6.37 libx11@1.6.9 libxext@1.3.4 libxrandr@1.5.2 libxrender@0.9.10 libxt@1.2.0
+ libxtst@1.2.3 make@4.2.1 openjdk@13.0 pkg-config@0.29.2 unzip@6.0 which@2.21 zip@3.0
location: gnu/packages/java.scm:2379:2
homepage: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/14
license: GPL 2+
synopsis: Java development kit  
description: This package provides the Java development kit OpenJDK.
relevance: 22

...
```

Is there a way to only show for example the name and the version of each respective package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the small utility program `recsel` (from `recutils` package):

```
$ guix search openjdk | recsel -p name,version
name: openjdk
version: 9.181

name: openjdk
version: 14.0
...
```